# Elasticsearch - Testing a Native Script

Tags: java, elasticsearch

I am testing my application that uses Elasticsearch using a test node. It's initialized like this:

```
protected class ElasticsearchTestNode {
  val cluster = s"${System.nanoTime}"
  val dir = TempDir.create(Some(cluster))
  val settings = settingsBuilder.put("path.data", dir.path)
  val node = nodeBuilder.clusterName(s"$cluster").settings(settings).local(true).data(true).node()
  val client = node.client()
```

One use case in the application needs to call a native script written in java similar to this blog post: http://www.spacevatican.org/2012/5/12/elasticsearch-native-scripts-for-dummies/.

I'm not sure how I can register the script with my test node. Is it possible?

Comment: Instead of using settings builder you can place `elasticsearch.yml` file on classpath and configure it there as specified in your example

Comment: any idea how could I use that to register a native script considering each test node has a folder in /tmp?